# How to get data from multiple tables using just one single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a conception problem I think, not a code problem, I have 4 tables in my database, QUESTION, INTERESTS, QUESTIONTAG, and a USER.

My tables structure :

```
INTEREST -- id
         -- user
         -- tagparent

QUESTION_TAG -- id
             -- tagparent
             -- tagchild ( unnecessary )
             -- question 

QUESTION -- id
         -- content and when published ( unnecessary )
```

I want to get 10 questions ordered by index_order ( field ) and are interesting for the USER, and I know he is interested by those questions using QUESTION_TAG association table that links between the question and the tag.

so the logic is this :

```
request 0 :  SELECT * FROM QUESTION WHERE id = ( results of request 1
- returns many ) ORDER BY index_order LIMIT 0,10
```

This request must return many results :

```
request 1 : SELECT DISTICNT question FROM question_tag WHERE tagparent
= ( results of request 2 - returns many )
```

This request returns many results too

```
request 2 : SELECT tagparent FROM interests WHERE user=9
```

So using SubQueries is not really that helpful.

I am stuck, and I wish I can find a solution just using a single request, without filtering the data with a back-end language.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to join these tables with the help of INNER JOIN?  Maybe show us what your table structures looks like.

Comment: of course I will try to edit my post

Comment: @monstertjie_za edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May Be This is what you are looking for.

```
select question.*, distinct question_tag.question, interests.tagparent
from question 
inner join question_tag on question_tag.question = question.id 
inner join interests on interest.tagparent = question_tag.tagparent 
where interests.user = 9
```

Comment: `distinct` must come first, and it must apply to all columns.

Comment: My mistake, yes it is what I am looking for. thanks a lot.